# Derivative of Dirac delta composed with a function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How can the distribution $\partial_{t}\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}(t))$ be written as something multiplied by the distribution $\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}(t))$?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle \delta_{\vec y(t)},\phi\rangle=\frac{d}{dt}\phi(\vec y(t) =\nabla \phi(y(t)) \cdot \vec y'(t)$$

Comment: As @Mark Viola points out, at the very best of all worlds you have a gradient of a δ-function, not something proportional to a  δ.

Comment: Here one can ask if there will be a difference of result depending on whether the "integration" is done w.r.t. $\mathbf x$ or $t$.